# Mysql Select with case statement and field comparison

Tags: mysql, case

I am selecting from a table with field comparison value e.g.

```
Select FieldA,FieldB,(FieldC-FIeldD) as Difference
```

and now want to actually select with values given to the Difference field e.g.

```
When Difference=0 then 'North'
When Different>0 and Difference<=90 then 'NorthEast'
When Difference=90 then 'South'
```

etc but am unable how to interject that into the Select. I already did this successfully in an update but the Select escapes me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a Sub-Select query would work well here.

Currently your statement look like:

```
Select FieldA,FieldB,(FieldC-FIeldD) as Difference from <TABLE>
```

Instead, you can have this in a sub-select like this:

```
select * from 
(
Select FieldA,FieldB,(FieldC-FIeldD) as Difference from <TABLE>
) sub_table
```

Now you can do your case statement in the outermost select statement:

```
select 
CASE
    When Difference=0 then 'North'
    When Difference>0 and Difference<=90 then 'NorthEast'
    When Difference=90 then 'South'
END as answer
from 
(
Select FieldA,FieldB,(FieldC-FIeldD) as Difference from <TABLE>
)
```

Comment: You don't need `Difference > 0` in the second `WHEN`, because cases are tried in order (I assume negatives can't happen). You also have a typo in the name `Different`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT FieldA, FieldB, 
CASE 
   WHEN Difference = 0 THEN 'North'
   WHEN Difference > 0 AND <= 90 THEN 'NorthEast'
   WHEN Difference = 90 THEN'South'
END AS Foo
FROM (
     Select FieldA, FieldB, (FieldC-FIeldD) AS Difference
)
```

Comment: This is not valid syntax. You can't write `WHEN > 0`.

Comment: Now it's just the same as the other answer.